# I have one question about data anlysis with python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, statistics

I have learned data analysis with python(CSV, Pandas), Thus I typed the code in python, today. but my code has an error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3,600'. As you can imagine the error occurred when data numbers were over the thousands. But I don't know what is that problem. because I checked my CSV(Excel) data. but they did not have any ','(comma) in CSV data. So, I repaired my code to settle the error. Even though I use the int(float()), data.replace(",", ""). but they have errors. Please tell me what is that problem.

```py
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = open('gender.csv', 'r', encoding = 'cp949')
data = csv.reader(f)
header = next(data)

name = input("Which city do you want to search: ")

m =[]
f =[]

for row in data:
    if name in row[0]:
        for i in row[3:103]:
            m.append(-int(i))
        for i in row[106:]:
            f.append(-int(i))
        break
        

plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5), dpi = 300)
plt.rc('font', family = 'Malgun Gothic')
plt.rcParams['axes.unicode_minus'] = False
plt.title(name + 'Population distribution by gender and gender in the region')
plt.barh(range(101), m, color = 'skyblue', label = 'Male')
plt.barh(range(101), f, color = 'red', label = 'Female')
plt.legend()
plt.show
```

error type:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,841'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  ```int()``` doesn't recognize ```1,841``` due to the ```,```.  You need to remove the comma.

Comment: Thank you, but I tried to remove the comma. However, according to the python note, the data does not have any commas. But the error happens...

Comment: Do you have any sample data that you can include in your post?

Comment: What is the separator in your CSV file?